# How can I customize the format of Python output?

Tags: python

I know basically nothing about `python` (I did know about it before but never took the time to try it out). I've started using `python` because I'm doing an A level course in computer science.

I wanted to know how to center align the output ?

What I've done to "center" align is:

```python
print ("------(<< the spaces didnt show up in post, so i used "-"'s)How long have you been alive")
```

But I feel that its the wrong technique to use, how do I do it properly?
Also, is it possible to change the colours of the output/runned view
for example have a title black and other writing blue, and the background yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method center() returns centered in a string of length width. Padding is done using the specified fillchar. Default filler is a space.

**SYNTAX**

```
str.center(width[, fillchar])
```

You could refer to the links below.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_center.htm

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center

Comment: I messed around with it and it only adds characters to the sides (the default being a Space, what I want it to do it automatically center align.

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically center align?

Comment: automatically align to the center of the python shell, like in html or something.

Comment: i don't think there is a way to do that. But, if you know the width of your python shell, you could enter that value in the str.center function.

Comment: ok, the (tiny) problem is that if someome has a different width shell to the one I use, the text wouldn't be centered